# Calling a function within the locationManager in Xcode that results in the distance between two coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, gps

I'm trying to call a function within the location manager that will give me the total distance traveled. My professor has provided the function that should be able to do this for us but I'm not sure how to call it. Or how to get the values to call it.

This is the locationManager I currently have:

```
    //This function is called everytime when location changes if allowed
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations
    locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude)
    myMap.setCenter(myLocation, animated: true)
    let myAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    myAnnotation.coordinate = myLocation
    myMap.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)
    myMarks.append(myAnnotation)
    myAnnotation.coordinate = myLocation
    //distance = distance + calculateDist(
}
```

and then here is the function that I would like to call

```
//Calculate distance between two locations (unit: mile)
func calulateDist(lat1:Double, lon1:Double, lat2:Double, lon2:Double) -> Double {
    var theta:Double
    var dist:Double
    theta = lon1 - lon2
    dist = sin(lat1 * 3.14/180) * sin(lat2 * 3.14/180) + cos(lat1 * 3.14/180) * cos(lat2 * 3.14/180) * cos(theta * 3.14/180)
    dist = acos(dist)
    dist = dist * 180 / 3.1415926535
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
    return dist
}
```

Comment: Actually you can do it using `CLLocation` class method `distance(from:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423689-distance without reinventing a wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what's missing for you is the previous location to allow you to calculate the distance (distance needs two locations).

Seems like you have a store of these, though, through the map annotations and what you can likely do is something like:

```
// before appending the new myAnnotation
let previousLocation = myMarks.last.coordinate
// You might have to do some optional unwrapping in the line above to get the coordinate out from the annotation
let distance = calculateDist(lat1: previousLocation.latitude, lon1: previousLocation.longitude, lat2: myLocation.latitude, lon2: myLocation.longitude)
```

Hopefully this gets you what you need!

Comment: Xcode had me unwrap
    `let previousLocation = myMarks.last.coordinate`
to
    `let previousLocation = myMarks.last?.coordinate`

it also had me unwrap the function call as well though, it changed it to
    `let distance = calculateDist(lat1: (previousLocation?.latitude)!, lon1(previousLocation?.longitude)!, lat2: myLocation.latitude, lon2: myLocation.longitude)`

and when I run it after unwrapping everything I get a

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

error and it crashes.